# How to connect database using simple html form field without using ASP, JSP or PHP

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I have two text field in a html page without using PHP or asp or java can we able to connect with sql database. As I am new to this kindly please help me currently i am using online database [Online database](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1)

This is what my HTML will look like

```
<form id="form" method="post">
     <input type="text" id="productName" placeholder="Product Name"/><br/>
      <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Description"/></br/></br/>
      <button>Retrieve Data</button>
 </form>
```

My current [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/dm2nj4ct/1/)

As I am new to this kindly please help me

Comment: In general you can't do that. What 'Online database' are you using? Or are you saying you use sqlfiddle for data storage?

Comment: thanks for reply actually i have my sql installed in my machine I have created one table name product and i have value to that table i want to know how to connect with database i just put the online database for my reference purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can connect a MySQL database to a HTML page without using another language such as PHP. Check out this simple [guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-with-php-in-6-steps/). All you have to do is replace the generic values such as "username", "password", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this with a server side language, such as PHP. You can't do this without the languages you mentioned (or with JS or another client-side language).

As per [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289234):

> One of the first rules of web app programming is that the client cannot be trusted - all client code can be (fairly easily) hacked. Put the important bits (like connection strings) on the server where the bad guys have to at least work a little harder to get to them.
>
> Your best approach would be to do what just about everyone else does - write a server based web app that connects to the database and delivers just the data to the client.

Comment: can you please let me know how to use with JS

Comment: @Mahadevan I meant to say that it **isn't** possible with JS. Javascript is a client-side browser, and as the answer says, it can be easily hacked. So don't do it. Learn PHP instead (really -- it's a great language!)... and AFAIK there isn't a way to do it.

Comment: the problem my project won't support for PHP :(